# How to monitor the process of placing any Parcel data in to persistent storage

Tags: android, parcelable, serializable, parcel

Since the [Parcel doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html) says that

> changes in the underlying implementation of any of the data in the Parcel can render older data unreadable.

So I wonder is there a way to monitor the process, so that we can prevent placing `Parcel` data to persistent storage.

Also, does the `Serializable` object has the same problem, if it does, how to monitor.

Answer (score 1):

> So I wonder is there a way to monitor the process, so that we can prevent placing Parcel data to persistent storage.

A `Parcel` is never written to persistent storage. That is part of the point of having `Parcelable` in addition to `Serializable`.

> does the Serializable object has the same problem

Changes in a `Serializable` class may cause problems when you try to read in older values.

> how to monitor

Since you are the one writing your `Serializable` objects to disk, monitor it yourself. There is no place that I can think of where Android will automatically write a `Serializable` class of yours to disk.

Comment: I have test Serializable, it crashes when you change the member type, other condition, it works fine, such as change the member name, remove or add a member.

Comment: I have encountered intentional write parcel to persistent storage, such as Parcel parcel = Parcel.obtain();
object.writeToParcel(parcel, 0);
contentValues.put("key", parcel.marshall());

Comment: @twlkyao: Whoever wrote the code in your latter question is violating the `Parcel` contract. If this is in the AOSP somewhere, file an issue. If this is in an app that you control, fix it.

Comment: Yes, this is in our app, I can find the call by search Parcel.obtain(), marshall or unmarshall, I will add some method try to prevent other people do this.